# Bash does not execute the certbot command

Tags: php, linux, bash

Bash does not execute the `certbot` command, how to find out why?

When I use `ls` command to test normal bash functions

php:

```php
$cmd = "/bin/bash /usr/local/openresty/nginx/html/pHpServer-PG/api/cert.bash test.com";
echo $cmd;
$ww = shell_exec($cmd);
var_dump($ww);
```

bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
certbot certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --webroot --agree-tos --no-eff-email --email email@gmail.com -w /usr/local/openresty/nginx/html -d $1 -d admin.$1 -d www.$1
```

I use php-fpm and nginx with user root

Some way to extract bash error?

Comment: To answer your question, you can debug the Bash script by setting `-x`. Something like `bash -x <my_script.sh>` or `bash -x certbot certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 ...`.

Comment: @jww return null in 2 options

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify the variable in `-d $1 -d admin.$1 -d www.$1` port of the code, so `$1`?

That suggests you're passing a domain name to the code.

You can also run the bash script with `bash -x`, so e.g. if you named your script `certificate.sh`, run

`bash -x certificate.sh domain.com`

where `domain.com` is your domain name.

Comment: no output at all? did you check certbot log for errors? it should be under `/var/log/letsencrypt` or similar. maybe it's certbot issue.